# Regex expression to get the string between two strings,or until either end of the main string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regex that gets the content between two strings, String1 and String2 but in case either of the two strings are not present I want to match until the end of the main string.
For example: `hi_foo123xyz2-3bar_hello`, `foo123xyz2-3bar` , `foo123xyz2-3` `123xyz2-3bar` and `123xyz2-3` the intended match is `123xyz2-3`.

I tried different approaches using Lookaheads and Lookbehinds and I feel that I only need a single step but It seems far from reach.
The closest I could get is something like this

```
(?<=foo).*?(?=bar|$)
```

I also tried

```
(?<=foo|^).*?(?=bar|$)
```

but it seems to break everything.

Comment: What relevance is the `sql` tag to your question? If nothing, please remove the tag.

Comment: Sorry if it confused you I just removed it, The regex is used in SQL so no programming is viable and that is why I added the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to match `^` *only* when there is no `foo` using this expression `^(?!.*foo)`, then create an alternation of that or a lookbehind for `foo`.

Similarly, use a lookahead for `bar` *or* end of input `$`.

```
(^(?!.*foo)|(?<=foo)).*?((?=bar)|$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/4xN3OsJaBLozgm).

Recall that alternations are match left to right - ie the right is only attempted if the left doesn't match.